# Gson: Convert empty body to empty JSON object {}

Tags: gson, retrofit

I'm using [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) with [Gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/). How to customize Gson to convert empty response (body is empty) to empty JSON object `{}` ?

```
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .setDateFormat("yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'.'SSS'Z'")
            .serializeNulls()
            .create();

    new RestAdapter.Builder()
            .setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL)
            .setEndpoint(Api.API_URL)
            .setClient(new OkClient(okHttpClient))
            .setConverter(new GsonConverter(gson))
            .setRequestInterceptor(new AddHeaderRequestInterceptor())
            .build()
            .create(Api.class);
```

**UPDATE**

My `NullAdapter` not used (`here` and `and here` not shown) - I got null

```
   Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .registerTypeAdapter(Object.class, new NullAdapter())
            .create();
   System.out.println(gson.toJson(null).toString()); // produce null

   class NullAdapter extends TypeAdapter<Object> {

        @Override
        public void write(JsonWriter out, Object value) throws IOException {
            if(value == null) {
                System.out.println("here");
                out.beginObject().endObject().close();
                return;             
            }
        }

        @Override
        public Object read(JsonReader in) throws IOException {
            System.out.println("and here");
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried [TypeAdapter](https://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/TypeAdapter.html)?

Comment: Did you find solution?

Comment: https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/1554 might have multiple comments which provide solutions for this.